# difference between folder/ and /folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rhel, directory-structure

I have a small confusion regarding a basic thing in paths i.e whats the difference between folder/ and /folder

I just want to understand whats the difference between both. I tried to search but didn't get a suitable information regarding this.

Comment: changed the title, because `/folder` is not a command, nor is `folder/`; they are *paths*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ya my bad for mistyped